# How did Gecko Moria created marine zombies in Marine War without Hogback around?

Tags: one-piece

Back at Marineford War. I noticed something, Gecko Moriah summoned marine zombies from nowhere instantly without Hogback around.These marine zombies have stitches which is only done by Hogback back in Thriller Bark. Some even take the form of animals which is another problem in its existence.

[image]

So how did Gecko Moria has done it?

Comment: Is there any reason he couldn't reuse bodies that had been made earlier?  He removed the shadows from most of his zombies himself (though those were eventually released.) He would only have to put in new shadows right?

Comment: @Kaine - I don't remember seeing many marine zombies during the Thriller Bark Arc. And when Hogback with unconscious Moria left the Thriller Bark they didn't bring with them any dead zombies.

Answer (score 4):

Hogback was useful for Moria, because he could stitch together different parts of separate bodies, thus  only using the strongest parts of those bodies. The best example for this is Sanji's zombie. He is essentially a penguin, but instead of the useless mouth, hogback replaced it with a dogs jaw.

If you look at the marine zombies, none of them has a dog head or bear hands. The closest to this category is the centaur on the left, but that's..."normal". A normal marine doctor should be able, to fix those bodies up.

Comment: Yes Hogback is very useful to Moria but my question is how did Moria summoned stitched zombies without Hogback around? I did re-watch the anime and the zombies just came out underground.

Comment: @bot Have you actually read my answer? Hogback's specilaity was, that he could stitch together different dead bodies, thus creating an ultimate zombie out of the best "ingredients". They were probably hiding there. It wasn't the first occasion, where we see enemies coming from underground

Comment: I don't question his specialty I salute it. Your answer is just explaining its ability. How could Hogback create new zombies if he is not around right.? Have you seen him(Hogback) around when Moriah summon those zombies from underground?

Comment: @bot If Moria needed Hogback for his ability, then it would be a bit weak in my opinion. Hogback is nit creating zombies, Moriah does, hogback only creates bodies.